# jqgrid filter toolbar deleted row

Tags: laravel, filter, null, jqgrid, toolbar

i'm using jQgrid with multiselect toolbarfilter. I use softDeletes and would like to filter deletes where !null.

I can filter null, but how do i filter not null?

Perhaps use a formatter?

Query:

```
        $query->select([
            "actions.id AS action_id",
            "actions.global AS action_global",
            "actions.name AS action_name",
            "actions.description AS action_description",
            "actions.deleted_at AS deleted",
        ])->withTrashed();
```

Columns:

```
        $grid->setColModel([
            ["name" => "action_id", "hidden" => true],
            ["name" => "action_name", "label" => __("actioncontroller.action_name")],
            ["name" => "action_global", "label" => __("actioncontroller.action_global")],
            ["name" => "action_description", "label" => __("actioncontroller.action_description")],
            ["name" => "deleted", "label" => __("deleted")],
        ]);
```

Filter:

```
$grid->setSelect("deleted", [1 => __('yes'), null => __('no')]);
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Kind regards

Comment: Do you use jqGrid for PHP product? If yes which version?

Answer (score 0):

so i found the solution.

A formatter didn't help, but if you make an if null statement in the RAW. It will filter on your select.

Query:

```
$query->select([
            "actions.id AS action_id",
            "actions.global AS action_global",
            "actions.name AS action_name",
            "actions.description AS action_description",
            DB::raw("IF(ISNULL(actions.deleted_at),'N','Y') AS deleted"),
        ])->withTrashed();
```

Filter:

```
$grid->setSelect("deleted", ["N" => __('no'), "Y" => __('yes')]);
```